# Opening outlook in safe mode via powershell

Tags: email, powershell, outlook, windows-10, powershell-3.0

**How do you open Outlook in safe mode by default?** Is there a powershell/cmd script I can use?

I'm assisting a user who's Outlook crashes after every 2nd email. The user doesn't experience these issues while opening Outlook in safe mode. User is currently able to access outlook in safe mode by holding down the ctrl key and double-clicking the Outlook icon. Looking for an easier solution for user such as a desktop icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy\Paste from [here](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/270):
- If you are using Windows Vista or Windows 7, then there is a Search box in the Start Menu. Here type `outlook.exe /safe`
- In Windows 8, the search box will automatically show when you start typing. So simply open the Start Screen and type `outlook.exe /safe`
- In Windows 10, there is a search box on the Taskbar by default but if you have set to hide this, it will automatically show when you start typing after opening the Start Menu as well. Here type `outlook.exe /safe`
- You can also create a new shortcut to outlook.exe and add the /safe switch;

First, determine the location of outlook.exe on your system. In general you’ll find it under;

32-bit version of Windows
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office 
64-bit version of Windows
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office 
If you can’t find it, do a search for outlook.exe or use OutlookTools (free) instead.

Once you’ve found outlook.exe we create a shortcut to it with the /safe switch to prevent Outlook from opening an extra window each time you click the shortcut or use your keyboard shortcut.

Right click on an empty space on your Desktop and choose New-> Shortcut
Type the path to outlook.exe between quotes or browse to its location via the Browse… button
Type a space behind that and /safe
The entire line should now look like this (example is for a 32-bit version of Outlook 2010 on a 64-bit version of Windows);
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" /safe
Click Next
Name your shortcut for instance: Outlook Safe Mode
Click Finish

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: don't forget to upvote and mark as answer, thanks ;)

Comment: ... and you can create that last shortcut remotely on your users' desktop with PowerShell ^^